# windows forms power symbol

Tags: c#, winforms

Using Visual Studio 2010, Windows Forms Application. When creating a click event for a button the function parameters are as follows:

(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)

What is the meaning of the power symbol? Google isn't helping me search this as it ignores special characters ><

I know in c# it is an exclusive OR operator but that seems irrelevant here.

Comment: That's a managed handle in managed C++. It's not C# code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like C++, not C#.

Did you see this in the documentation? If so, switch the documentation mode to C# and things will make a lot more sense.

If Visual Studio is generating this, you probably accidentally created a C++ project.